# sklearn.feature_selection chi2 identifies same unigrams and bigrams for different labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been using a code that i found online on multi-classification using scikit: https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f. Ive been using my own dataset which consists of tweets that relate to hate speech, anyway ive been trying to find the terms that are the most correlated with each of the labels i have. The labels are identified as **Hate** and **Non-Hate**. The results i have been getting for the most correlated unigrams and bigrams for both  labels are exactly the same. I am just wondering what is wrong? ive tried using the dataset that is provided by the website and it works perfectly on that.

my results look like this :

```
# 'Non-Hate':
  . Most correlated unigrams:
. idiot
. stupid
  . Most correlated bigrams:
. fucking idiot
. fucking bitch
# 'Non-Hate':
    . Most correlated unigrams:
. idiot
. stupid
  . Most correlated bigrams:
. fucking idiot
. fucking bitch
```

the code used is:

```
df['category_id'] = df['Code'].factorize()[0]
category_id_df = df[['Code', 'category_id']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('category_id')
category_to_id = dict(category_id_df.values)
id_to_category = dict(category_id_df[['category_id', 'Code']].values)
df.head()


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=3, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Tweet).toarray()
labels = df.category_id
features.shape
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import numpy as np
N = 2
for Code, category_id in sorted(category_to_id.items()):
  features_chi2 = chi2(features, labels == category_id)
  indices = np.argsort(features_chi2[0])
  feature_names = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())[indices]
  unigrams = [v for v in feature_names if len(v.split(' ')) == 1]
  bigrams = [v for v in feature_names if len(v.split(' ')) == 2]
  print("# '{}':".format(Code))
  print("  . Most correlated unigrams:\n. {}".format('\n. '.join(unigrams[-N:])))
  print("  . Most correlated bigrams:\n. {}".format('\n. '.join(bigrams[-N:])))
```

Answer (score 0):

With just two classes, these *should* be the same.  The chi-squared test is finding the features that are most discriminative (in some sense) between the two classes.  Your reference is different, because the target used (`labels == category_id`) is a one-vs-rest discrimination.  A unigram/bigram that is very indicative of *not* being in a class will still have a high chi2 test value for that class.